# How to write a timeout function for until loop in Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I have the following Makefile

```
ready:
    until docker-compose logs some_svc | grep "ready"; do echo -n .; sleep 1; done
```

I want to wrap it with a timeout function.

```
define check_timeout
    timer=0
    $(1); do
        ((timer++));
        if [[ "$$timer" == 60 ]]; then
            exit -1
        fi
        sleep 1
    done
endef

ready:
    $(call check_timeout, until docker-compose logs some_svc | grep "ready")
```

But I got the following error:

```
$ make ready
timer=0
until docker-compose logs some_svc | grep "ready."; do
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [ready] Error 2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems.

The first one is that make always uses `/bin/sh` to run recipes.  It doesn't matter if your personal interactive shell is bash, zsh, or csh, it will always use `/bin/sh`.  On many systems, `/bin/sh` is not bash but a basic POSIX shell like `dash`.  Many of the elements of your script are not valid POSIX shell scripting.  So if you want to be at all portable (to, for example, Debian/Ubuntu based systems) you can't rely on these bash-isms in your makefile.

Either that or you have to specifically tell make that you want bash, with:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

Of course that will fail on any system that doesn't install bash at all.

Secondly, just because you put the script into a `define` block doesn't absolve you of the need to use backslashes if you want the recipe to be on a single logical line and be passed to a single shell invocation.  You need semicolons between commands (such as between `exit -1` and `fi`, etc.) and you need backslashes at the ends of lines.

This should work:

```
define check_timeout
    timer=0; \
    $(1); do \
    timer=$$(expr $$timer + 1); \
    if [ "$$timer" = 60 ]; then \
        exit -1; \
    fi; \
    sleep 1; \
    done
endef

ready:
        $(call check_timeout, until echo ready | grep "ready")
```

Answer (score 1):

You will encounter endless problems with Makefiles in your career. Many of them can be solved by asking yourself the question:

> Does this need to be in a Makefile, or would it be easier for me to put this functionality into a bash script and simply call that script from my Makefile?

To improve the readability of your Makefiles and to make your life easier put this functionality into a bash script and call it from your Makefile.

### Makefile

In the Makefile we use the `timeout` command to put a time limit on the script we want to call. We also handle the error by making use of *in case of error* `||` operator.

```
ready:
    timeout 60 bash until_docker.sh || exit -1
```

### until_docker.sh

In the bash script we have implemented the functionality we wish to call

```sh
until docker-compose logs some_svc | grep "ready"; do echo -n .; sleep 1;
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.